# Swift says I have an extra initializer argument. Why?

Tags: swift, initialization

Why am I unable to use a parent-class initializer?

Here's the API that I'm following:

[image]

Here's the error:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MapKit

class UserInMapView:MKAnnotationView {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        println("{UserInMapView} init coder.")
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func doSomething() {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(-20, -20, 50, 50))
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0;
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor;
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        self.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}

// =======================================================================================================================

class PinpointMap:NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.3315644,-122.0296575)
    var profilePhoto:UIImage
    var userID:String?

    init(userID:String, profilePhoto:UIImage) {
        self.userID = userID
        self.profilePhoto = profilePhoto
    }


    func getAnnotationView() -> MKAnnotationView {
        // Using MKAnnotationView protocol:
        let thisView = UserInMapView(annotation: self, reuseIdentifier: "UserInMap")
        //        this.profileImage.image = profilePhoto
        return thisView
    }

}
```

What am I missing here?

---

I've made changes per feedback; but the compiler still insist that I have the required init():

[image]

So made some changes via compiler hints and came up with this:

[image]

The compiler's happy; but it seems awkward to have to plug in the decoder init().

Is this the correct way to instantiate a MKAnnotationView object?

Comment: I think the problem is that you need to implement `init(annotation:reuseIdentifier:)` in your MKAnnotationView subclass, even if all you do is call `super` in it.

Comment: If my guess about that turns out to be right, you might like to submit a bug report to Apple, since this really doesn't seem like correct behavior. Initializer inheritance is turning out to be really tricky, and the error message you are getting is far from helpful...

Comment: I still have to deal with the required init(coder...).  I'll submit a bug report for Apple's feedback.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have implemented a designated initializer `init(coder:)` and that is the *only* initializer you have implemented. Hence, Swift is complaining that that is what you must call. I think you can work around this by also redeclaring `init(annotation:reuseIdentifier:)` in your subclass implementation, even if all it does is call `super`.

Comment: Yes... I had to redeclare the init().  But I also have to deal with the init(code...).  I'm going to file bug report with Apple for their feedback.

Comment: I filed the bug report: #18961079.

Comment: It's not a bug - Swift classes only automatically inherit their superclass's initializers if they meet certain criteria. See "Automatic Initializer Inheritance" in the [Initialization documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_324).

Comment: It is not the inheritance that is the bug, @NateCook. It's that the compiler complaint is unhelpful.

Comment: Oh, carry on then. Those error messages are bananas across the board.